# Посоветуй Cron Node js библиотеку

Tags: node.js, express, cron

И так, у меня стоит бизнес задача сделать пользователям напоминалки.Я нашел несколько библиотек которые с этим справляются на отлично. Но в целом, если сервер упадет/обновится. Задачи поставленные через эти библиотеки слетят.

Подскажите как мне из моего node js приложения. Взаимодействовать с cron операционной системы.

Comment: Возможно самый простой вариант будет child_process.exec('cronttab -l > tmp.txt && echo "* * * * * command" > tmp.txt && crontab tmp.txt && rm tmp.txt')

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: agenda, node-cron